# Loading one to many relation synchronously

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We are having a simple one-to-many relation  (do not pay attention to the broken pluralization):

```
QuickOrder = DS.Model.extend({
        quickOrderAddresss: DS.hasMany('quickOrderAddress', {
            async: true
        })
    });

QuickOrderAddress = DS.Model.extend({
        quickOrder: DS.belongsTo('quickOrder'),
        ...
        state: DS.attr('string'),
        city: DS.attr('string'),
        street: DS.attr('string')
        ...
    });
```

Because the server uses quite sick JSON format we implemented our own adapter that is able to search an order by ID:

```
QuickOrderAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({

        find: function(store, type, id) {
            .........
            return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                jQuery.getJSON(addressesUrl).then(function(data) {

                    //lots of ugly stuff here

                    Ember.run(null, resolve, result);
                }, function(jqXHR) {
                    jqXHR.then = null; // tame jQuery's ill mannered promises
                    Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Now we want to remove `async: true` and use `async: false` instead. Can you please give me an example of the JSON format that ember data expects if the loading is synchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the Ember guide (http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships).

Something like:

```
{
  "quickOrder": {
    "id": 1,
    "quickOrderAddresss": [1,2]
  },    
  "quickOrderAddress": [{
    "id": 1,
    "quickOrder": 1,
    //blah blah more stuff
  },{
    "id": 2,
    "quickOrder": 1,
    //blah blah more stuff
  },
}
```

Comment: Note that I am misspelling "quickOrderAddresss" as you are above, but it shouldn't affect your results.

Comment: That link is now broken.